# Copy a column from one sheet to multiple sheets based on sheetname

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy column A from one sheet "OPT1"
to the same column in multiple sheets - "OPT1_1", OPT1_2" etc

but it doesn't seem to like the range?

```
Sub Copy_MN()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Sheets("OPT1").Select
        Range("A:A").Copy
        If ws.Name Like "OPT1_*" Then
            'ActiveSheet.Select
            ws.Range("A:A").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my proposition:

```
Sub Copy_MN()
Dim ws As Worksheet

  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.name Like "OPT1_*" Then
        ws.Range("A:A").Value = Sheets("OPT1").Range("A:A").Value
    End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: ah i see - approach it from the other way. Thks works perfectly